# Cast a dynamic variable to a given Type

Tags: c#, dynamic, c#-4.0

I have a dynamic variable where i store, depending of the context, an object who can be of several types (here *Foo* and *Bar*)

```
dynamic myvar;
myvar = new Foo();
//or
myvar = new Bar();
```

Foo and Bar contains differents methods.
To get access to methods of myvar, i thought it was possible to use casts like

```
(Foo)myvar.mymethodoffoo();
(Bar)myvar.mymethodofbar();
```

But it's not working, i get **(dynamic expression) this operation will be resolved at runtime** in the code editor.

So, How can i cast a dynamic object to get the available methods and properties from the editor ?

Thank's by advance.

Comment: I am not sure your approach is the best, I would rather strongly type the variable using an interface or a common base class.

Comment: If you're going to give the compiler enough information in the form of a cast to statically resolve the call then *why is the type dynamic*? This doesn't make any sense to me. The point of dynamic is that you use it when the type is *not* known at compile time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cast operation (`(SomeType)x`) has a [lower precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) than the `.`.
Therefore, your code is parsed as `(Bar)(myvar.mymethodofbar())` — the cast happens after the method call.

You need to add parentheses:

```
((Bar)myvar).mymethodofbar();
```

Comment: Nice! Do you mind telling us when you are actually NOT on SO? (so the rest of us can squeeze in some answers)

Comment: @tzup: Between 11PM and 8AM EST.

Answer (score 2):

```
((Foo)myvar).mymethodoffoo();
((Bar)myvar).mymethodofbar();
```